loop through visible cells cause infinity loop in a special case
I have bellow code to loop through visible cells in my worksheet

    With InvoiceSheet
        For Each RangeCnt In POListSheet.Range("A2:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)


It works fine, but in special case, when LR=2 it doesn't work. in this special case resulted cells are (1,1),(2,1),....
Could you find why this happend.
Thanks.

For Each RangeCnt In IIf(LR = 2, POListSheet.Range("A2"), POListSheet.Range("A2:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))

I guess that is because you are using it after Autofilter. The issue arises because SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) considers all visible cells, even those outside the range you specify. In this case, the cells in the same row as well as the rest of the worksheet's blank rows.
For example, if you put a breakpoint and test for the value of POListSheet.Range("A2:A2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address, you may get something like $1:$2,$6:$1048576 in the immediate window.
Does this help?
Dim LR As Long

'~~> Test with different values
LR = 2 ' 15, 35

'~~> Define the target range
Dim targetRange As Range
Set targetRange = POListSheet.Range("A2:A" & LR)

'~~> Get the range of visible cells after applying autofilter
Dim visibleCells As Range
On Error Resume Next '<~~ Handle cases with no visible cells
Set visibleCells = Intersect(targetRange, targetRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
On Error GoTo 0 '<~~ Reset error handling

'~~> Check if there are visible cells
If Not visibleCells Is Nothing Then
    'With InvoiceSheet
        '~~> Loop through visible cells
        'For Each RangeCnt In visibleCells
            '~~> Rest of the code
        'Next RangeCnt
    'End With
    Debug.Print visibleCells.Address
Else
    MsgBox "No visible cells found to process.", vbExclamation
End If


Could you pls. try this Sub chk() For Each cel In Range("A6:A6").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) Debug.Print cel.Address Next cel End Sub . ONLY SINGLE STEP!!! otherwise list all. (at least for me). Hide a row somewhere.

@Blackcat: If you are not using "Autofilter" then it is very simple but if you are using it after an autofilter then it is a different ballgame alltogether... See my edit on the post...

I'm afraid not really understand what you mean. With the above code I get $A$1 $B$1 $C$1 $D$1 $E$1 $F$1 $G$1 $H$1 $I$1 $J$1.......

@Blackcat: When you have data in a worksheet and you apply autofilter and only the first row is visible (as in user's case) then POListSheet.Range("A2:A2").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address will return $1:$2,$6:$1048576 and not $A$2
